# Cloud technology used by the Pegasus-PaaS Manager

Tags: fiware, fiware-pegasus

When I use the Pegasus component of FIWARE and deploy a product, I would like to know which technology does Pegasus use to deploy virtual machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pegasus contains an application that makes use either of Chef or Puppet technologies in order to install a product into the supplied Virtual Machine.

Comment: Nice, to know it but which Cloud technology you can use to deploy VM?

Comment: Hi again, the cloud technology used to deploy virtual machines is Openstack.